# How to get value between "::before" and "::after" using Xpath?

Tags: xpath

How should I modify my xpath:

```
//@*[contains(., 'order-num')]
```

to get number of orders after

> ::before

from this screenshot?
[Page](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2018-New-Women-Beach-Casual-Shirt-dress-Vestidos-Summer-O-Neck-Short-Sleeve-Green-Black-Parties/32920600258.html) for test.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images of code, edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the code highlighting in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
//span[@class="order-num"]/text()
```

to get required value

Comment: thank you. But I'd like to use anything that contains "order-num" instead of class, not exactly "order-num". Is it possible?

Comment: @Jooms , so `id` attribute `j-order-num` is also not suitable?

Comment: yes, j-order-num is not suitable. On some pages id and class of this element may slightly differ but it always contains "order-num".

Comment: @Jooms , Do you mean `//span[contains(@id, "order-num")]/text()` instead of `//span[@id="j-order-num"]/text()`

Comment: This is much better //*[contains(@id, "order-num")]/text(). But can I use any parameter instead of id?

Comment: @Jooms , class name? :) There are not so many attributes in `span` node... You can use attributes of preceding `div`... is it OK?

Comment: Andersson, I managed to get what I want. //*[contains(@*, "order-num")]/text() It works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
substring-after(//span[contains(@class,'order-num')][1]/text(),'::before')
```

Comment: Thank you @zx485. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried it on this page: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2018-New-Women-Beach-Casual-Shirt-dress-Vestidos-Summer-O-Neck-Short-Sleeve-Green-Black-Parties/32920600258.html

Comment: `::before` is not a *text* , but CSS *pseudo-element*. You canNOT locate it with CSS or XPath locators!