# Cannot write dynamic xpath for element in page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This is the Url: http://automationpractice.com/index.php

[I want to select "casual dresses", but when I tried the "Women" WebElement is selected instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GY2f4.png).

How can I write the dyanmic xpath to select "casual dresses"?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes, but i got Syntax error at visibilityOf method, it's showing like"The method visibilityOf(WebElement) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (By)"-@Prophet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until page is loaded, then hover over Women title, the wait until the menu is open and then click on the Casual Dress item.
It's best practice to keep variables in the top of class, not inside the code hardcoded.
Try this:

```
//Define expected conditions explicitly wait
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
//Define Actions object instance
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
//define locators
String womenTitleXpath = "//a[@title='Women']";
String up = "/..";
String womenCasualDressXpath = womenTitleXpath + up + "//a[@title='Casual Dresses']";
//Wait until the element is visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.xpath(womenTitleXpath)));
WebElelemnt womenTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath(womenTitleXpath));
//Hover over the Menu to open it
action.moveToElement(womenTitle).build().perform();
//Wait until the menu item is visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.xpath(womenCasualDressXpath)));
//Finally click on the desired element
driver.findElement(By.xpath(womenCasualDressXpath)).click();
```

Comment: and cruisepandey what effort this user has put that you decided to give out answers? Just curious to know

Comment: Just trying to help, without additional thoughts.

Comment: Does this rule applies to everybody?

Comment: Mainly yes, until I see person who is known as unthankful.

Comment: Also, I do not know everything, so I answer only when I know or at least think it will be helpful.

Comment: Oh is it, but what you did before when others did the same thing. Mock them :)

Comment: It was only once, I think, where the OP was known unthankful person. He was asking the same question third time while we had answered him there great, detailed answers but he didn't accept any answer, even didn't write "thanks" to anyone.

Comment: Thank You very much to helping me, I got Syntax error but instead of "visibilityOf()" method, I used "visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()" then it Resolved.

Comment: OK, it's quite same since the only difference between these methods that method I use treats single element, first matching the passed locator while your methode returns a list of elements, but it is also waits for at least one element, not actually waiting for "all" the elements since it doesn't know how many elements to wait for

Comment: I have one doubt Brother, Why Combined (womenTitleXpath + up+ "//a[@title='Casual Dresses']"), why we are Write this"/.."

Comment: This is how the page HTML built there. `//a[@title='Casual Dresses']` is not directly below / inside the `//a[@title='Women']` element but they are both inside their mutual parent element who is the direct parent of `//a[@title='Women']`

Answer (score 0):

You can find by reading the `<li>` items,this is my result:

xpath:

```
//*[@id="block_top_menu"]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a
```

full xpath:

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/header/div[3]/div/div/div[6]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/a
```

Comment: I tried above Xpath but i get ElementNotInteractableException Error..

Comment: What about this one?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53209031/how-to-get-value-between-before-and-after-using-xpath

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick python script that clicks that "Casual Dresses" button. You have to use ActionChains to hover over "Women", then identify and click "Casual Dresses":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php")

womenElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Women"]')))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(womenElement).perform()
casualDressesElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[title="Casual Dresses"]')))
casualDressesElement.click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: OK, in the future please include your code in any question, and specify the coding language.  In the mean time, check out @Prophet 's solution :)

Comment: Thank you for your code, yeah compulsory i do it next time when i want to post any question.